# How to up value in new column, when occur 0?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this `df`:

```
data = {'Name': ['T', 'J', 'K', 'J', 'M', 'A', 'J', 'K','L', 'o', 'j' ], 'Match': [0,1,2,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,1]}

Df =  pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to apply column, which show season for each match. Season sholud be more then previous every time when match value is 0.
What is important, number of matches in every season is different.

Out sholud be:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hLtk.png)

What do you suggest?

************** UPDATE  ***********

Thanks for Your answers.

But what when 0 occur one after another, like this:

```
Match': [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,0,1]
```

And I want to up season number, only when occur 0 first time.
I mean range from 0 to VALUE different than 0, but this VALUE should precedes next 0.

So this should be like this:

```
'Season': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4]
```

Out:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hLtk.png)

What do you sufgest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Season'] = (df['Match']==0).cumsum()
```

Turn zeros to True (1) and the rest to False (0), and cumulatively sum them, it will increment only when seeing a True

**UPDATE:**

Now you changed to require consecutive zeros to be in the same season.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Match': [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,0,1]})
temp = df['Match']==0
df['Season'] = (temp & ~temp.shift(1).fillna(False)).cumsum()
```

Comment: Can you see my actual problem? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you remove your answer, and edit your question, by adding for example "UPDATE", and put everything new under it?

Comment: I did it. I updated

Comment: Welcome! The idea is pretty much the same, only this time I additionally check whether a True is preceded by a False (by using `shift`). You know, if it's preceded by a False, it's the first zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
c = 0
out = []
for i in df['Match']:
    if i == 0:
        c+=1
        out.append(c)
    else:
        out.append(c)
```

df['ses']=out

output:

[image]